# Extract rows with column name matching a specific pattern in kdb q

Tags: design-patterns, kdb

I have a table with multiple patterns of char string. I need to extract the data with specific pattern .

```
tableName: ([] description: ("ABC 1.45 Apr-24"; "ABC 1.34 1/2/23"; "DE 2.456 Mar-22";"CBD 4/3/2023 5.78"; "XYZ 3.7 Jun-25"; "PQR 4.12 May-21"; "MNO 7.345 Jul-23"))
```

From the above table i need to extract data which is of pattern "?* *.*** ???-??"

The pattern "?* *.*** ???-??" is divided into three parts

1. first part - i need it to be in letter which is the name(can be any number of letters) (ex. AB or ABC or ABCD etc)
2. second part - i need it in decimal values format , can be more than one decimal value or max available
3. third part - date format in the pattern APR-24

**i tried the below , but does not show any data**

```
q)pattern: "^[A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+\\.[0-9]+ [A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+$"  / Pattern to match

q)result: select description from tableName where description like\: pattern

q)result
```

OUTPUT AS

```
description
------------
"ABC 1.45 Apr-24"
"DE 2.456 Mar-22"
"XYZ 3.7 Jun-25"
"PQR 4.12 May-21"
"MNO 7.345 Jul-23"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method you could implement entirely within Q:

```
tableName:update description:{" " vs x} each description from tableName; // Split into components
tableName:select from tableName where 3=count each description, all each description[;0] in .Q.A, all each description[;1] in (.Q.n,"."), description[;2] like "[A-Z][a-z][a-z]-[0-3][0-9]"; // Apply clauses
tableName:update description:{" " sv x}each description from tableName; // Rejoin into strings
```

This first breaks up the strings by a space delimiter. Then the 4 elements of the where clause are:

1. Check if there are 3 elements after slitting up by a space delimiter.
2. Check if all elements in the first text block are Alphabetic Capitalised (.Q.A)
3. Check if all elements in the second text block are Numeric and Decimal (.Q.n,".")
4. Use Q's [inbuilt regex](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/) functionality to check if the last text block adheres to our pattern

Result:

```
description       
------------------
"ABC 1.45 Apr-24" 
"DE 2.456 Mar-22" 
"XYZ 3.7 Jun-25"  
"PQR 4.12 May-21" 
"MNO 7.345 Jul-23"
```

Answer (score 0):

kdb+ does not implement full regular expression pattern matching.

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/

It supports `?` `*` `[]` `^`

If you want full support you can use an external library:

- https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/#regex-libraries
- https://code.kx.com/developer/libraries/regular-expression-pcre2/
- https://github.com/KxSystems/ffi/blob/master/examples/pcre.q
- https://kx.com/blog/advanced-pattern-matching-and-text-manipulation-in-kdb-with-embedpy/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
q)tableName: ([] description: ("ABC 1.45 Apr-24"; "ABC 1.34 1/2/23"; "DE 2.456 Mar-22";"CBD 4/3/2023 5.78"; "XYZ 3.7 Jun-25"; "PQR 4.12 May-21"; "MNO 7.345 Jul-23"))
q)select from tableName where{p:" "vs x;all(all p[0]in .Q.a;not null"F"$p 1;any p[2]like/:"[a-z][a-z][a-z]-",\("[0-9]";"[0-9]");3=count p)}each lower description
description
------------------
"ABC 1.45 Apr-24"
"DE 2.456 Mar-22"
"XYZ 3.7 Jun-25"
"PQR 4.12 May-21"
"MNO 7.345 Jul-23"
```

Explanation for the where clause:

```
p:" "vs x /split string by whitespace delimiter
all p[0]in .Q.a /checks 1st part are all alphabets
not null"F"$p 1 /cast 2nd part string to float to see it is not null
any p[2]like/:"[a-z][a-z][a-z]-",\("[0-9]";"[0-9]") /check 3rd part matches [a-z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9] OR [a-z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9]
3=count p /check the split count
```

EDIT: updated based on @SeanHehir suggestions!

Comment: I think you could improve this by using `lower` on `description` before passing it into your lambda. That will allow you to only have to compare against .Q.a and "[a-z]". 
The original regex seems to allow for one or more numbers in the date part also (e.g. I think APR-1 is valid based on what's provided) so you could do something like:
`any p[2]like/:"[a-z][a-z][a-z]-",\("[0-9]";"[0-9]")` to account for that.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Updated my answer based on your suggestions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this using a finite state machine in q also (https://code.kx.com/q/basics/regex/#regex-in-q). But the performance is likely worse than the other answers posted here.

```
m:(0;
   {2*all(x?" ")#x in raze .Q`a`A};
   {3*all(" "vs x)[1]in .Q.n,"."};
   {4*x like"[A-Z][a-z][a-z]-[0-9][0-9]"}
   )
f:{4=m/[1;" "vs x]}
```

If you know in advance that your column will only contain 2 spaces:

```
q)select from tableName where f each description
description
------------------
"ABC 1.45 Apr-24"
"DE 2.456 Mar-22"
"XYZ 3.7 Jun-25"
"PQR 4.12 May-21"
"MNO 7.345 Jul-23"
```

Otherwise, you can filter on that condition also:

```
q)select from tableName where 2=sum each" "=description,f each description
description
------------------
"ABC 1.45 Apr-24"
"DE 2.456 Mar-22"
"XYZ 3.7 Jun-25"
"PQR 4.12 May-21"
"MNO 7.345 Jul-23"
```